# Is retro telecom / networking on topic?

Tags: discussion, scope

So we had an interesting request on the Network Engineering Stack Exchange asking about X.25, Frame-Relay and ATM switching.  The dedicated X.25 devices from the 70's and 80's are pretty solidly retro but I haven't seen much coverage of them.  Would questions pertaining to these old NCP's, switches and the protocols of the time be on-topic for this forum?

Comment: Yes please. My first computer job was writing code that turned x25 trace logs into something useful.

Answer (score 12):

I would say yes, definitely.

Communications and networking have always been an integral part of computing.  Therefore, they should be welcome here.

We do have questions regarding protocols; Econet and Novell Netware to name just two.  so, bring them on.

Comment: Having spent a certain amount of time on (what are now) retro computers implementing (what are now) retro protocols, I'd say "yes".

Comment: Agreed, as long as it sticks to usage/higher protocol levels (I got a complete X25 test setup/network in my basement :)). Going too deep into X25 might be borderline.

Comment: Would ISDN be considered retrocomputing? It's old, but not quite *that* old.